# How to print the class name that includes the module?

Tags: ruby

I have a module (`module A`) that reads a JSON file based on the names of the classes that include it (`B.json` for class `B`, `C.json` for class `C`, etc.) and defines some methods and constants for them.

The only place I found that I have access to the class name was `self.included` method, but I couldn't access it from outside it.

I tried different things, including setting instance variables from `self.included` or the constructors of the classes, but had no luck.

Here is my code example:
https://replit.com/@EricNa1/CornyClutteredKeyboardmacro#main.rb

```
module A
  puts "class name doesn't print here:",  self.name
  # I want to read a JSON file here based on the class name (e.g. B.json for B, C.json for C, etc.)
  
  def self.included(clazz)
    puts "but it prints here", clazz.name
  end
end

class B
  include A
end

class C
  include A
end

B.new()
C.new()
```

prints

```
class name doesn't print here:
A
but it prints here
B
but it prints here
C
```

(Also I'm not sure why 'class name doesn't print here: A' gets printed only once even though it's supposed to be called once from B and once from C)

Comment: When defining `module A` it's not known where it will be included. This happens at runtime and therefore, you have a callback method which is invoked the moment `A` is being included. Why not move the custom logic into the `included` callback?

Comment: Maybe you are under the impression that `module A` is evaluated each time you call `include A`. That is not the case. It is evaluated once, prior to `B` and `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, it prints:

```
class name doesn't print here:
A
```

not because you have included module, it prints because of module created.
You can comment your class and see that message still prints.
Next, method:

```
def self.included(clazz)
    puts "but it prints here", clazz.name
  end
```

is called when module is included in class or somewhere, class doesn't call it at all, because class even does not have access to that method, because the method is with 'self' and module is included, not extended to class.
So you can fetch all class names which include that module with something like that:

```
module Super 
  @klass_names = []

  def self.included(klass)
    # puts "Class which included me " + klass.name 
    @klass_names << klass.name
  end 

  def self.show_class_names
    p @klass_names
  end 
end 

class M
  include Super
end 

class B 
  include Super 
end 

Super.show_class_names
```

This code is not perfect at all, but at least it gives you an idea.